# How do I format different lines of text differently, from a textfield created in AS3, with text populated from a txt file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, action

So I have a flash file in AS3, latest version of flash.

It creates a text box in AS3. It then uses AS3 to grab text from a text file (2 lines) and loads it in. I then used further code to format the text size, font, color etc.

But NOW...I need line 1 of the text box to be a certain format (large, caps) and the second line to be a different format (smaller, no caps)

Here is all my code below:

```
//BEGIN TXT LOADER
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var winnerText:TextField = new TextField();

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
winnerText.text = e.target.data;
addChild(winnerText);
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("EditableText.txt"));

//BEGIN TEXT BOX FORMATTING
winnerText.width = 1920;
winnerText.height = 300;
winnerText.y = 430;

//BEGIN TEXT & FONT FORMATTING
var casinoBranding:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

casinoBranding.size = 90;
casinoBranding.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
casinoBranding.font = "Bliss Pro";
casinoBranding.leading = -50;
winnerText.defaultTextFormat = casinoBranding;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "first line"? Is this all the text before the first newline (`\n`) or the first line before natural word wrapping occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a TextFormat like @Aaron suggests. Another way of doing is to use stylesheets. Here is an example

http://snipplr.com/view/39474/as3-textfield-and-stylesheet-example-created-in-actionscript/

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sure there must be another way.

I found a solution, which is to use text ranges, like this

    myTextField.setTextFormat(myformat, 49, 65);

But unfortunately the ranges will change as per the text in the text document...

(Please advise me on how to format code in comments)

Comment: @user2442016 You can use backticks (`\`code\``) to format code in comments. (Click the "help" link nex to the comment input area.)

Comment: @SameerJain `TextFormat` does not have to apply to the entire text.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Voted down, remove it. Different TextFormat can be applied in one textfield to as many different part of texts as you want.

Comment: Sorry missed the ranges part. I will amend answer. Like @Aaron suggest you can use text format too

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `TextFormat` to a specific range of text using [`TextField/setTextFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat()).

To apply a different text format to the first line of text you can do this:

```
var casinoBranding:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var casinoBrandingFirstLine:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
// ... apply formatting options

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    winnerText.defaultTextFormat = casinoBranding;
    winnerText.text = e.target.data;
    winnerText.setTextFormat(casinoBrandingFirstLine, 0, winnerText.getLineOffset(1));
}
```

Note that if word wrapping is involved it changes what the "first line" really means.

Comment: Would you be able to integrate this with my existing code so I can paste it? I've tried but it seems to be conflicting with my code.

Also you forgot a period between casinoBranding and firstLine.

And I think firstLine applies to a different type of text box....

Comment: No, I didn't "forget a period" and it does not "apply to a different type of text box". `casinoBrandingFirstLine` is just a different `TextFormat` for however you want the first line of text of your `winnerText` to look like. Just set whatever formatting properites you want. You can copy paste 3 lines of `winnerText` code into your `onLoaded` handler, the rest of the code is the same.

Comment: Aaron. I owe you a beer, or a coffee.